# Getting post lists from facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm trying fetch list of post from given set of facebook pages using restfb(java)

List fbPages = Arrays.asList("178697151159/posts", "538560813021153/posts");

JsonObject fetchObjectsSubResults = client.fetchObjects(fbPages, JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("fields","shares,created_time"),Parameter.with("limit", 5));

But I'm getting a runtime error from facebook api as following.. IS there any body that can help me out to resolve this or is this impossible (

Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 178697151159/posts?,538560813021153/posts? (code 803, subcode null)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1278)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1195)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1136)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1058)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1020)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchObjects(DefaultFacebookClient.java:476)
    at main.main(main.java:75)

Comment: This looks like you are using a method that expects to be passed only page _ids_, but you pass `page-id/posts` into it, which the Graph API does not recognize as a page id (no surprise there.) You need to go check the documentation for the SDK/client library you are using there, for what the _right_ way is to specify what edges/fields you want from what ids.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 1 call per page. SO it should look like:

```
Connection<Post> postConnection = client.fetchConnection(pageId+ "/posts", Post.class, Parameter.with("fields","shares,created_time"), Parameter.with("limit","5"));
```

Depending on your use case, you can run over the `postConnection` with a for loop to get all posts or take the data from the first page of the result set with `postConnection.getData()`.

In both cases you can eventually work with a Post type and access the fields your are interested in. The other fields are left null.

BTW working with multiple ids in a single call or request these ids one after another makes no difference to the Facebook calls. The amount that is internally calculated is the same; in your case 2.

Comment: Additionally I'd like to explain the correct syntax for the call your question started with.

The correct endpoint for fetching posts from multiple pages on Facebook looks like `graph.facebook.com/posts?ids=178697151159,538560813021153`. 

I think this is not supported in RestFB, only calls without endpoint will work. But this is just a guess and I did not checked this call in depth. You may open a issue on Github if this is important...

Comment: @Norbet yes, it was working for one page that is why I tried to use multiple pages in the same way(I know it is stupid) . Actually my concern was the number of api calls I can make I though it is different if I make the call including all the page ids at once. if there is no difference I can use a loop for this. Thanks. BTW do you have any Idea how to reduce the number of api calls make for this pupuse.

Comment: Depends on your use case. If you like to fetch all posts you should increase the limit, because that is the limit per page. If you only need the first 5 posts, everything's okay. The only thing that should help in that situation is a webhook. You subscribe to the page feed and receive an update as soon as something new happens on the feed. For example if a new post is written. So you only need to poll data from Facebook if there is something new.

Comment: @Norbert I tried getting all posts from a facebook page using resFB, `But there is a mismatch in total post count`, when I try to get the posts for same facebook page through browser. And I confirm manually that I didn't get some recent posts from the page. Number of Posts retrieved `with restFB is 2922` and retrieved through`(HTTP) URL in browser is 3044`. What is the reason for this and how can I overcome this If I want the all posts from that page using restFB ?

Comment: @ParthVishvajit first, this is another problem, but nevertheless here's an answer. The more you go into the past the less Facebook guarantees to give you all posts. In some Facebook bug report a Facebook engineer explained this. Further you may have some users that don't allow the platform access. Their posts/comments and so are not visible in the Graph API. Perhaps you can take a missing post and try to fetch its data via Graph API...